# How do i get the cell id of a table

Tags: javascript, dom

This is the board drawing function

```
this.drawBoard=function(){         
                document.write('<table id="newGame">');
                for(let i=0;i<boxes;i++){
                    document.write('<tr>');
                    for(let j=0;j<boxes;j++){
                    document.write(' <td id=" '+ i +' , '+ j + ' " ');
                    document.write('</td>'); 
                    }
                    document.write('</tr>');
        
                }
                document.write('</table>');
                b.onClickEvent();
        
            }
```

While this is the function to get the id

i found that by changing the `0` index in line `clicked = cell.getElementsByTagName("td")[0].id;` I can get to the column I want but don't know how to manipulate it to get the exact cell id

```
this.onClickEvent=function() {
                let table = document.getElementById("newGame");
                let rows = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
                for (i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
                    let  currentRow = table.rows[i];
                    var createClickHandler =
                      function(cell) {
                        return function() {
                          clicked = cell.getElementsByTagName("td")[0].id;
                          console.log(clicked);
                          let numbers=[];
                          clicked.replace(/(\d[\d\.]*)/g, function( x ) { var n = Number(x); if (x == n) { numbers.push(x); }  })
                          b.spliceGrid(numbers[0],numbers[1]);
                          numbers=[];
                    
                    
                    };
                  };

                  currentRow.onclick = createClickHandler(currentRow);
            }
        
      }
```

Comment: Are you attaching an event handler to each cell? Don't. Attach a single event handler to the table as a whole and use `event.target.closest("td")` to find the cell that was clicked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tables elements have properties like `rowIndex` or `cellIndex`, you don't need to use `id` for each cell.

Then, you even have access to any cell you want to get or set anything on it, like change it's background ( to pink ):

```
myTable.rows[2].cells[1].classList.add('BgPink');
```

this way:

```js
const myTable = newTable(4,5);

myTable.rows[2].cells[1].classList.add('BgPink');


function newTable( rowCount, cellCount )
  {
  const TableX = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('table'))
    ;
  for( let r=0; r < rowCount; ++r )
    {
    let newRow = TableX.insertRow();
    for( let c=0; c < cellCount; ++c )
      { 
      newRow.insertCell().textContent = `${r},${c}`; 
      }
    }
  return TableX;
  }


myTable.onclick = e => // event delegation method 
  {
  if (!e.target.matches('td')) // to accept only clicks over a <TD> element
    return;
  let
    index_Cell = e.target.cellIndex
  , index_Row  = e.target.closest('tr').rowIndex
    ;
  console.clear();
  console.log('clicked on :', index_Row, index_Cell );
  }
```

```css
table  {
  border-collapse : collapse;
  }
table td {
  padding    : .2em .8em;
  border     : 1px solid darkblue;
  text-align : center;
  cursor     : pointer;
  }
.BgPink {
  background : pink;
  }
```